# Github Actions not finding pytest tests in Django project

Tags: django, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions

For some reason, the Actions aren't finding any tests when I use Pytest on a Django project. If it helps, I had the tests initially using the Django testing framework and it still wouldn't find any tests.

This is the django.yml:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.12]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        cache: 'pip' # caching pip dependencies
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        pytest -v
```

The tests can be found in the main branch. There is no problem with test discovery on my local computer, the test file names follow the naming procedure.

This is the pytest.ini file:
`[pytest] DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = playlist_analyser.settings python_files = tests.py *_tests.py`

This is what an example of a file name looks like:
`PlaylistAnalyser/playlist_analyser/tests/playlist_tests.py`

This is what an example of a test looks like in the file (there are no errors):

```
@pytest.fixture
def handler():
    yield PlaylistHandler()

#------------------ Get_Avg_Of_Attribute Tests ------------------#
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_avg_attributes(handler):
    playlist_url = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6cUbe8r2kP140bL0Z2HHXV?si=89cbce6452b84b10"
    playlist = handler.get_playlist(playlist_url)
    avg_attributes = playlist.get_avg_attributes()
    
    assert avg_attributes['Energy'] == 77
    assert avg_attributes['Danceability'] == 46
    assert avg_attributes['Acousticness'] == 17
    assert avg_attributes['Valence'] == 39
    assert avg_attributes['Loudness'] == -5.86
    assert avg_attributes['Tempo'] == 131
    assert avg_attributes['Duration'] == 222
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
Run pytest -v
  pytest -v
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.1/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.1/x64/lib
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.1, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.3.0 -- /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.1/x64/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/runner/work/PlaylistAnalyser/PlaylistAnalyser
plugins: django-4.7.0
collecting ... collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.02s =============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for some reason, it fixed itself, no changes made.